# Branch in remote showing up on GitHub but not when I do git branch -r

Tags: git, github-api

I am working on a project with a remote team. They created a branch (r_branch) that I can see when I'm in GitHub:

```
master
r_branch (and it tells me that it's 6 ahead)
```

When I do git branch -r, here's what I get:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
```

No mention of r_branch. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `git fetch` recently? Git won't know about what's going on at the remotes, unless you explicitly tell it to communicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you done `git fetch`?

What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: * remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master      tracked
    r_branch new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)

Comment: That definitely sounds like you should be able to do a "git fetch" and after that you will be able to create a local branch tracking the new remote branch by doing "git checkout --track origin/r_branch"